# Join two MySQL Tables and get result from categories

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT art.*,arg. FROM rd_articles AS art 
LEFT JOIN rd_argument AS arg ON art.cat=arg.id WHERE art.enabled=1 ORDER BY art.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This is simple join query
Article table structure is

```
ID    cat    Description     Date
 1      1    Abc             08-01-2014
 2      1    Aaa             10-01-2014
 3      2    Abcv            11-01-2014
 4      3    Aaa             12-01-2014
 5      3    Aaa             14-01-2014
```

Arguments table is

```
ID   Name
 1    A
 2    B
 3    C
```

I want pick last updated(Date) one item from each cat.
How ?

Comment: That query you list at the top is all kinds of broken. You select as N and A, then use art. and arg. ??

Comment: Oh It was typing mistake

Comment: In reality, your dates are of course stored under a DATE data type, right?

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that the `enabled` column is in `rd_articles`:

```
SELECT art.*, arg.*
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM rd_articles
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT cat, MAX(date) AS maxdate
    FROM rd_articles
    WHERE enabled = 1
    GROUP BY cat
  ) md ON rd_articles.cat = md.cat AND rd_articles.date = md.maxdate
) art
LEFT JOIN rd_argument AS arg ON art.cat = arg.id
```

The innermost query gets the maximum date for each category, then joins it to the `rd_articles` table to get only those `rd_articles` rows that have the latest date for each article. That becomes the `cat` alias, which is then left-joined to the `arguments` table just like in your original query. You can add the `LIMIT 10` at the end if needed; I wasn't sure what to do with that.

Note that if there's a tie for a category's latest date, you'll get more than one row for each category. If a tie could happen you'll need to break the tie somehow, for example by using the description or the ID. Let me know if that's the case and I'll update my answer.

Comment: I think there's more subquery than you strictly need there?!!

Comment: Yes I have enable column :)

Comment: @Ed Gibbs Actually I want pick one article per argument (last article under argument)

Comment: @Strawberry: I'm 99.9% sure you're right. If `rd_argument` were inner joined I'd have used one less subquery, but I was worried about the left join. I don't have MySQL access today and can't test the "single-subquery with left join" option, so I chickened out and went with something I could be sure of without testing/tweaking.

Comment: Ah, but you're never more than a click away from an sqlfiddle ;-)

Comment: @EthicalRajesh - I called them "categories" because of the `cat` column in `rd_articles`, but the column relates to the `id` column in `rd_argument`. So I *think* that category=argument. Is that correct?

Comment: Well played @Strawberry :)  I forgot all about SQLFiddle.

Comment: @Ed Gibbs I'm using it with list mysql_fetch_assoc so not working :(

Comment: SELECT art.*, arg.* FROM (  SELECT * FROM rd_articles
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT argum, MAX(id) AS maxid
    FROM rd_articles
    WHERE enabled = 1
    GROUP BY argum
  ) md ON rd_articles.argum = maxid.argum AND rd_articles.id = md.id
) art
LEFT JOIN rd_argument AS a ON art.argum = arg.id DESC LIMIT 10"

Comment: I think id is better then date so picked [article id]

Comment: If the ID is an auto-increment then yes, it should be fine. I'll be offline for a few hours, heading home from a client site, so I'm afraid I can't pursue this any further for today. I hope I've been able to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ART.*, ARG.*
FROM ARTICLE AS ART
INNER JOIN RD_AGRUEMENT AS ARG
ON ARG.ID = ART.ID
WHERE (ID, DATE) IN
(SELECT ID, MAX(DATE) FROM ARTICLE GROUP BY ID)
```